# seleniumを使ったスクレイピングでボタンをクリックする方法が知りたい

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-maps

最近seleniumを使ったスクレイピングを勉強し始めたものです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

言語はpythonでVScodeを用いて実行しています。

やりたいことは、Googlemapのタイムラインを自動でダウンロードすることなのですが、
タイムラインを開くmenuボタンをクリックしようとしたところ、エラーになってしまいました。

実行しようとしてエラーが出てる箇所は以下の通りで
メニューボタンのXPATHフルパスを指定してます。

```
menu_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/button').click()
```

コードにXPATHを指定したHTML

```html
<button jslog="158811;track:click" aria-label="メニュー" jstcache="137"   jsaction="navigationrail.more" class="wR3cXd jHfBQd"> <div class="NP7r5c"> <div class="cc4Ofc XjupRb"></div> </div> </button>
```

Comment: 「エラーになってしまいました。」とのことですが、エラーメッセージをそのまま（個人情報以外）質問に追記してください。

Comment: `find_element()`で獲得したものをメソッドチェインで`click()`するなら、行頭の`menu_btn = `は不要なのでは？ あるいはこちらの仕様説明 [【Python】click・・・要素をクリックする](https://www.seleniumqref.com/api/python/element_set/Python_click.html) のように個々の処理で2行に分けて記述してみてはどうでしょう？